# How to access a button press from the /joy node, while outside the callback function in ROS python

Tags: python, opencv, ros

I'm building a small robot and I'm trying to create two different modes:

The first one is a manual control with a joystick, using the `/joy` Node.
The second is an automated mode, where it detects a black line and drives on it.
My problem is that I want to quit this mode when pressing a button. Here is the simplified base function of the program:

```py
def callback(data):
    rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + "motor variables: %s, %s, %s", data.axes[2], data.buttons[2], data.buttons[3]

if data.buttons[2] == 1:
   automode = 1

if data.buttons[3] == 1:
   automode = 0

if automode == 1:
    manual(data)

if automode == 0:
    automatic(data)


def automatic(data):
    while True:
       # This is the function that works,
       # but the problem arises when I want to exit it:
       if cv2.waitKey(1) & data.buttons[3] == 1:
          break
```

Originally, it was `cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q')`, but since it needs to be accessed by a controller, I can't use it.
The base problem is that the `data.buttons[3] == 1` doesn't get accessed in the while loop, but I don't know how to change my code such that it actually changes when pressing the correct button.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I googled the possibility to use global variables, but in my understanding, it just saves the entry and doesn't "switch" to the callback function to look out for a buttonpress.

Answer (score 0):

You should use global variables here. Callback functions will always be running and updating as long as you don't tear down the subscriber. In the following example it would look something like:

```
button_pressed = 0
def callback(data):
    global button_pressed
    button_pressed = data.axes[3]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. unfortunately it doesnt get recognized and still stays in the while loop. could it be anything else?

Comment: @CoolerMann you need to verify that is where the correct button press/value is in the message then. And did you actually set up a subscriber and initialize the ros node anywhere? Because your example doesn't include that.